# MySql how to use index with different date types

Tags: mysql, indexing, date-range

I'm using MySql and I need to compare two tables' date columns, in the first(t1) the date is 'DateTime' and in the second the date is 'timestamp' which has an index on it.
And I want MySql to use this index.

I wish to find the same date

First I tried with date() function like:

Select *
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where date(t1.date) = date(t2.date)

but it didn't use the index.

Then I tried with greater than or between

Select *
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where t2.date between TIMESTAMP(t1.date) and TIMESTAMP(adddate(date,interval 1 day))

But this didn't use the t2.date index as well because("Range checked for each record (index map: 0x6)")

Comment: those two do very different things, one compares just the date part and one looks for a day's range of times but not starting at midnight.

Comment: You select all rows - index won't be used.

Comment: The 1st select cannot use an index as you convert datetime and timestamp to date data type. The 2nd one cannot use indexes as each record has to be checked against a list of date ranges.

Comment: Datetime and Timestamp are for the most part compatible.  Are you only trying to match on the date part of those columns in each table?  If, so no indexes can be used.  Your best solution would be to add a Date type column to each table and use a simple update query to populate those columns.  Index them, and you will have an optimal query for matching rows.  Whether or not this is something worth doing depends on how often this query will be run, and what the purpose of it is.  It might take a while to get a result but if it's a one off, then let it tablescan.

Comment: `DATE(...)` makes it not sargable, hence indexing has no benefit.

Comment: @gview The purpose of this is to update an int column in table t2 with a value from table t1 on the same day

Comment: @Dima Your question is in regards to why your query is table scanning.  An update query that requires a join is going to have the same problem as a select with a join.  I have done this type of operation many times.  The answer provided demonstrates a couple of techniques you can use, but your tables must be innodb

Answer (score 1):

If this is a join which you will using often it will be beneficial to have an index. One simple way to do this is to create a virtual date column, calculated from the datetime/timestamp column and then index it.
Here is a simple example.
NB at the end I try to create an index on date(created) but it is not seen as a possible in the `explain select` following whereas the index on the virtual column is recognised.

> ```
> create table table1(
> id int primary key auto_increment,
> created datetime 
>   default current_timestamp,
> col1 varchar(10),
> dayCre date as (date(created)) virtual
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table table2(
> id int primary key auto_increment,
> created timestamp 
>   default current_timestamp,
> col1 varchar(10),
> dayCre date as (date(created)) virtual
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into table1 (col1) values
>  ('test 1');
>  insert into table2 (col1) values
> ('test 2');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from table1;
> select * from table2;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | created             | col1   | dayCre    
> -: | :------------------ | :----- | :---------
>  1 | 2022-03-29 22:26:22 | test 1 | 2022-03-29
>
> id | created             | col1   | dayCre    
> -: | :------------------ | :----- | :---------
>  1 | 2022-03-29 22:26:22 | test 2 | 2022-03-29
> ```

> ```
> explain select * 
> from table1 t1
> join table2 t2 
> on t1.dayCre = t2.dayCre;
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                     
> -: | :---------- | :---- | :--------- | :--- | :------------ | :--- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :-----------------------------------------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | null       | ALL  | null          | null | null    | null |    1 |   100.00 | null                                      
>  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | null       | ALL  | null          | null | null    | null |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)
> ```

> ```
> create index idx_table1_dayCre
> on table1(dayCre);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create index idx_table2_dayCre
> on table2(dayCre);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> explain select * 
> from table1 t1
> join table2 t2 
> on t1.dayCre = t2.dayCre;
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref                   | rows | filtered | Extra      
> -: | :---------- | :---- | :--------- | :--- | :---------------- | :---------------- | :------ | :-------------------- | ---: | -------: | :----------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | null       | ALL  | idx_table1_dayCre | null              | null    | null                  |    1 |   100.00 | Using where
>  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | null       | ref  | idx_table2_dayCre | idx_table2_dayCre | 4       | db_26819291.t1.dayCre |    1 |   100.00 | null
> ```

> ```
> create index idx_t1_created 
> on table1((date(created)));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> explain select *
> from table1 join table2
> on date(table1.created) =
> table2.dayCre;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra      
> -: | :---------- | :----- | :--------- | :--- | :---------------- | :---------------- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :----------
>  1 | SIMPLE      | table1 | null       | ALL  | null              | null              | null    | null |    1 |   100.00 | null       
>  1 | SIMPLE      | table2 | null       | ref  | idx_table2_dayCre | idx_table2_dayCre | 4       | func |    1 |   100.00 | Using where
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7717b945acf7a9e8dbf06ee38e3af633)*

Comment: This is an interesting aid towards a solution.  MySQL docs seem to suggest that an index on a virtual column would require innodb.  Can you verify?  Also, just for the sake of completeness, one of the OP's 2 tables had a timestamp and the other a datetime value.  I am confident that makes no difference in regards to your solution, but you could update it to match by having table1 or table2 be built from the datetime.